# Conectar SpringBoot com PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

Estou tentando conectar o banco com o SpringBoot e estou achando que meu problema é aqui:

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
# Set here configurations for the database connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springbootdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "create-drop" the database
# schema will be automatically created afresh for every start of application
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop


# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Esse é meu pom.xml

Inclusive o drive está instalado como podem ver:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Arquivo pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.wladimir</groupId>
    <artifactId>wladimir-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>wladimir-api</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency> 

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Esse aqui é meu banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aceito sugestões.

Essa é a mensagem de erro:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:990) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1022) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:250) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:193) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.wladimir.money.WladimirApiApplication.main(WladimirApiApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]

2017-11-13 15:51:20.037 ERROR 6092 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:250) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:193) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.wladimir.money.WladimirApiApplication.main(WladimirApiApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1031) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:990) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1022) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

2017-11-13 15:51:20.045  INFO 6092 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-11-13 15:51:20.056  INFO 6092 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-11-13 15:51:20.066 ERROR 6092 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2017-11-13 15:51:20.067  INFO 6092 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@af31e4: startup date [Mon Nov 13 15:51:14 GMT-03:00 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-11-13 15:51:20.070  INFO 6092 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-11-13 15:51:20.071  INFO 6092 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-11-13 15:51:20.071  INFO 6092 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-11-13 15:51:20.072  INFO 6092 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro?

Comment: acabei de atualiza, desculpe por não ter colocado a mensagem erro.

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro não tem relação com o Postgre.

Lendo o erro você consegue ver a seguinte mensagem: "The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured."

O que deve estar acontecendo é que você está tentando rodar a aplicação com a mesma no ar.

Pare o tomcat e certifique que a aplicação está fora (basta acessar o link http://localhost:8080).

Obs: Para parar o tomcat basta clicar em um quadrado vermelho que fica localizado no canto direito superior da aba Console.

Feito isso suba o projeto novamente, se der algum erro em relação ao banco, comente aqui novamente.